Jetpack Compose LazyColumn too much background
I have a LazyList with some values:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
        .background(color = Color.Red),
    state = listState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 15.dp, bottom = 40.dp),
) {
    items(collectionListState.value) { collection ->
        CollectionListItem(
            collectionName = collection,
            navigateToCollection = { navController.navigate("DcodeList/${collection}") },
        )
        if (collectionListState.value.indexOf(collection) < collectionListState.value.lastIndex) {
            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = 6.dp,
                        end = 6.dp,
                        top = 2.dp,
                        bottom = 2.dp,
                    ),
                thickness = 2.dp,
            )
        }
    }
}

I want to set the background to only my items WITHOUT the contentPadding. It looks awful. I want to have some extra space after the last element.
Is it possible to apply the background to items only?
Or is there some other option to achieve the same result without contentPadding?
I saw there's a Modifier.clipToBounds but I'm not sure how to use it.
How it looks vs. how it should look:
 

Can you provide an illustration of how it currently looks and how you would like it to look?

A yes sure , I actually meant to do that but forgot

Using Modifier.background on Individual Items that will apply the background color to your items only, excluding the content padding in your LazyColumn.

It will but then i cant have the round corners only on the top and the bottom without some additional conditions in LazyColumn

It sounds like you are doing wrong way to adjust item decoration and padding.
Try this code. It is exactly what you want.
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
        .background(color = Color.Red)
) {
    items(8) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = "hello")
        }
        HorizontalDivider(thickness = 2.dp)
    }
}

